# What is the minimum value of "initial-scale" in meta viewport tag?

Tags: html, css, viewport, meta

While experimenting with the `meta viewport` tag I noticed that any value less than 0.25 for initial-scale is treated as 0.25. E.g. all of the following

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.25">  
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.1">  
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.01">  
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale= ">
```

render the page same. So,

> - Is the minimum allowed vale of "initial-scale" in meta viewport tag 0.25?
> - What is the default value of initial-scale?
> - Why don't initial scale take it's default value, instead of taking 0.25, when blank space is given to initial scale as `initial-scale=`?

Answer (score 8):

The W3C states

> The initial-scale, minimum-scale, and maximum-scale properties
>
> The properties are translated into 'zoom', 'min-zoom', and 'max-zoom'
>   respectively with the following translations of values.
>
> 1. Non-negative number values are translated to  values, clamped
>      to the range [0.1, 10]
> 2. Negative number values are dropped
> 3. `yes` is translated to 1
> 4. `device-width` and `device-height` are translated to 10
> 5. `no` and unknown values are translated to 0.1

Src: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-device-adapt-1/#translate-meta-to-at-viewport

With the above given, the minimum should be 0.1, the default 0.1 and when no value is set, the default is used.

So the browser you tested it on most likely use the default, but since it appears to not go lower than 0.25, as it doesn't in your test cases, one can't say if it does or does not use the default.

Comment: I guess it uses `1` as the default value when the whole viewport tag is omitted or the `initial-scale` portion is omitted.

Comment: @user31782 I'm pretty sure it doesn't, and if you test without setting `initial-scale` and using `initial-scale=1`, you'll see a big difference ... more to read and see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: The quoted text doesn't say anything about the default. Actually if you follow the link to the `zoom` etc. property these map to, you'll see that the default is `auto`.

Comment: @VladimirPanteleev -- Point 5 states: _`no` and unknown values are translated to 0.1_, but it is somewhat more complexed than that, to simply say the default value is `auto`, as based on if one use a mobile or desktop and so on, it picks up values from the UA stylesheet etc. Also, different combinations of properties render different outcomes, hence I referenced/linked W3C.

Comment: 1) I don't think that's accurate 2) I downvote inaccurate posts (which improves the website) and remove the downvote / replace with upvote once the inaccuracy is fixed (the site allows changing your vote if the post is edited).

Comment: @VladimirPanteleev -- 1) The time spent on down vote and comment (in this case, given you state the default is `auto`), is the same as if to edit my answer, so plenty of time to fix my answer. 2) My interpretation is based on W3C's info, stating _when **no** or unknown values_ is used for a property, it defaults to 0.1, which clearly point 5 states. The default value for a property that is never used is of course different, hence the link so one can see what that might be (in some cases `auto`), though not was the OP asked for.